# Circular Linked List In Ascending Order Java

Tags: java, linked-list

My task is to implement a circular linked list in java (ascending order) but the problem is that it is going in an infinite loop

I have created a class of Node in which i have define two elements.

```
public class Node {
    public int element;
    public Node next;

    public class Node {
        int element;
        Node next;
    }
}
```

Now in the second class of List i have made a insert function i have define a Node head=null in the start and create a new nNode .After that i am checking in the head section if head==null then the first element will be nNode. After inserting the first element i will compare the next element and the head element if the head element is greater than it will shift next and the new nNode will be the head. Since it is the circular linked list it is working but it is also going in an infinite loop.

This is the List class in which i have use the node class variables

```
public class List {
    void insert(int e) {
        Node nNode = new Node();
        Node tNode = head;
        nNode.element = e;

        if (head == null)
            head = nNode;                      
        else if (head.element > e) {                        
            nNode.next = head;
            head=nNode;
        } else {
            Node pNode = head;

            while (tNode.next != head && tNode.element <= e) {
                pNode = tNode;
                tNode = tNode.next;
            }

            pNode.next = nNode;
            nNode.next = tNode;
            tNode.next=head;                                           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean that your `while`-loop is not terminating. Did you debug it? In which situations does it happen?

Comment: tNode.next=head; this situation but this code is the most important part of the circular list. @Thomas

Comment: it points the last node to the 1st node and thats what we do in the circular linked list . The last node have the reference of the first one

Comment: If I didn't miss something `tNode.next=head;` might indeed be the problem. Consider inserting an element somewhere in the middle, `tNode` would not be the last node then and thus would not have `head` as its next node.

Comment: hmm yes what will be the solution to it ..

Answer (score 1):

I have created on sample program for circular linkedlist which hold name and age of given element.
It has `add()`, `remove()` and `sorbasedOnAge()`  (Sorting is implemented by first getting clone and convert it into  simple linked list. Then use merge sort so that performance of O(nLogn) could be achieved.)

If you like it don't forget to press like button.

```
package com.ash.practice.tricky;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class CircularLinkedList implements Cloneable{

Node start;

public Node getHead() {
    return start;
}

CircularLinkedList setHead(Node startNode) {
    start = startNode;
    return this;
}

public void add(String name, int age) {

    if(name==null) {
        System.out.println("name must not be null.");
        return;
    }

    if(start == null) {
        Node node = new Node(name,age);
        start = node;
        node.next = start;
    } else {

        Node node = new Node(name,age);
        Node temp = start;
        while(temp.next != start) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = node;
        node.next = start;
    }
}

public CircularLinkedList clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException{  
    return (CircularLinkedList)super.clone();  
}  

public boolean remove(String name) {
    if(name==null) {
        return false;
    } else if(start==null) {
        return false;
    } else if(start.getName().equals(name)) {
        if(size()>1) {
            Node temp = start;
            while(temp.next!=start) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp.next = start.next;
            start = start.next;
        } else {
            start = null;
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        Node temp = start;
        Node next = null;
        Node prev = null;

        while(temp.next != start) {
            String currName = temp.name;
            if(currName.equals(name)) {
                next = temp.next;
                break;
            } else {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
        if(next == null) {
            return false;
        }
        prev = temp.next;
        while(prev.next!=temp) {
            prev = prev.next;
        }
        prev.next = next;
        temp = null;
        return true;
    }
}

/*  

public Node getPrevious(String name, int age) {
    Node curr = new Node(name,age);
    Node temp = curr;
    while(temp.next!=curr) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    return temp;
}

 */

public int size() {
    int count = 1;
    if(start != null) {
        Node temp = start;
        while(temp.next!=start) {
            count++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    } else return 0;
    return count;
}

public int listSize() {
    int count = 1;
    if(start != null) {
        Node temp = start;
        while(temp.next!=null) {
            count++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    } else return 0;
    return count;
}

public void display() {
    if(start == null) {
        System.out.println("No element present in list.");
    } else {
        Node temp = start;
        while(temp.next != start) {
            System.out.println(temp);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}

public void displayList() {
    if(start == null) {
        System.out.println("No element present in list.");
    } else {
        Node temp = start;
        while(temp.next != null) {
            System.out.println(temp);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}

public Node getPrevious(Node curr) {
    if(curr==null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        Node temp = curr;
        while(temp.next!=curr) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return temp;
    }
}

Node getMiddle() {
    Node result = null;
    Node temp = start.next;
    result = start.next;
    Node end = getPrevious(start);
    end.next = null;

    while(temp.next!=null) {
        if(temp.next.next!=null) {
            temp = temp.next.next;
            result = result.next;
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static CircularLinkedList SortCollections(CircularLinkedList list) {
    return SortCollections.doSortBasedOnAge(list);
}

private static class Node {
    Node next;
    String name;
    int age;

    Node(String name,int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "name = "+name +" : age = "+age;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + age;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Node other = (Node) obj;
        if (age != other.age)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}

private static class SortCollections {

    static Node mergeSort(Node head) {
        if(head == null || head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }

        Node middle = getMiddle(head);
        Node nextHead = middle.next;
        middle.next = null;

        Node left = mergeSort(head);
        Node right =  mergeSort(nextHead);
        Node sortedList = sortedMerged(left, right);
        return sortedList;
    }

    public static  CircularLinkedList doSortBasedOnAge(CircularLinkedList list) {
        CircularLinkedList copy = null;
        try {
            copy = list.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(copy!=null) {
            Node head = copy.getHead();
                            Node end = copy.getPrevious(head);
            end.next = null;
            Node startNode = mergeSort(head);

            CircularLinkedList resultList = new CircularLinkedList().setHead(startNode);
            return resultList;
        } else {
            System.out.println("copy is null");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Node sortedMerged(Node a, Node b) {
        if(a == null) {
            return b;
        } else if(b == null) {
            return a;
        }

        Node result = null;
        if(a.getAge() > b.getAge()) {
            result = b;
            result.next = sortedMerged(a, b.next);
        } else {
            result = a;
            result.next = sortedMerged(a.next, b);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static Node getMiddle(Node head) {
        Node result = null;
        Node temp = head;
        result = head;

        while(temp.next!=null) {
            if(temp.next.next!=null) {
                temp = temp.next.next;
                result = result.next;
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CircularLinkedList list = new CircularLinkedList();
    Collections.sort(new LinkedList());
    list.add("ashish", 90);
    list.add("rahul", 80);
    list.add("deepak", 57);
    list.add("ankit", 24);
    list.add("raju", 45);
    list.add("piyush", 78);
    list.add("amit", 12);
    //list.display();
    /*System.out.println("---------------- size = "+list.size());
    System.out.println(list.remove("deepak"));
    //list.display();
    System.out.println("---------------- size = "+list.size());
    System.out.println(list.remove("ashish"));
    //list.display();
    System.out.println("---------------- size = "+list.size());
    System.out.println(list.remove("raju"));
    //list.display();
    System.out.println("---------------- size = "+list.size());
    list.add("aman", 23);
    System.out.println("---------------- size = "+list.size());
    list.display();
    System.out.println("Previous Node of second node is : "+list.getPrevious(list.start.next));
    System.out.println("Previous Node of start node is : "+list.getPrevious(list.start));
    System.out.println("Previous Node of piyush node is : "+list.getPrevious("piyush",78));*/
    list.display();
    System.out.println("---------------- size = "+list.size());
    //System.out.println(list.getMiddle());
    CircularLinkedList newList = CircularLinkedList.SortCollections(list);
    newList.displayList();
    System.out.println("---------------- size = "+newList.listSize());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the following situation:

The list contains elements B,C,X. Now you want to insert A and then Z.

```
void insert(int e) {
    Node nNode = new Node();  //the new node, step 1: A, step2: Z
    Node tNode = head; //step1: points to B, step2: points to A
    nNode.element = e; 

    if (head == null) { //false in both steps
        head = nNode;
        head.next = head; //I added this line, otherwise you'd never get a circular list 
    } //don't forget the curly braces when adding more than one statement to a block
    else if (head.element > e) {  //true in step 1, false in step 2                     
        nNode.next = head; //A.next = A
        head=nNode; //A is the new head, but X.next will still be B
    } else {
        //you'll enter here when adding Z
        Node pNode = head; //points to A because of step 1

        //when tNode = X you'll start over at B, due to error in step 1
        //the condition will never be false, since no node's next will point to A
        //and no node's element is greater than Z
        while (tNode.next != head && tNode.element <= e) {
            pNode = tNode;
            tNode = tNode.next;
        }

        //in contrast to my previous answer, where I had an error in my thought process,
        //this is correct: the node is inserted between pNode and tNode
        pNode.next = nNode;                        
        nNode.next = tNode; 

        tNode.next=head; //delete this
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are at least the following problems in your code:

1. `tNode.next=head;` is not necessary, since if you insert a node between `pNode` and `tNode`, `tNode.next` should not be affected (and if `tNode` is the last node, `next` should already point to the head, while in all other cases this assignment would be wrong).
2. In the two branches above, where you set `head`, you're not setting the `next` element of the last node to `head`. If you don't do this when adding the first node, that's not necessarily a problem, but leaving that out when adding a new head (second condition) you'll produce an incorrect state which then might result in endless loops

What you might want to do:

Remove the `tNode.next=head;` statement.

If you add a new head locate the last node and set the head as its next node. That means that if you have only one node, it references itself. If you add a node at the front (your second condition) you'll have to update the `next` reference of the last node, otherwise you'll get an endless loop if you try to add an element at the end.

Comment: can u please can u make a algorithm it would be easy for me to understand through algorithm

Comment: its really confusing...!!

Comment: @mathlearner what's confusing? Try to implement the first two paragraphs below "What you might want to do:". It's basically just an additional assignment to `next` for closing the circle and a if-else branch after the loop.

Comment: it is going over to my head.. !! thanks for your help.

Comment: in my program pNode is the previous Node and tNode is the current node and i donot understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: @mathlearner I'm sorry, I had an error in my answer. I'll update it.

Comment: @mathlearner sorry for the confusion, I always had one loop-iteration too much in my head and didn't realize it until your last comment. Part of the reason for this are the relatively abstract variable names, so I'd like to give a piece of advice: prefer more descriptive names like `prevNode` or `previousNode` over `pNode` since that helps in understanding what they are meant for (especially if you re-read that code after a while  - like several months).

Comment: @mathlearner you might want to state where you get the NPE and whether you made sure that `next` is never null as I stated before. Also note that I only slightly adjusted your code, so the error/bug is still in there. Fixing it is a learning exercise for you.

Comment: i have done exactly the same which you have stated in your paragraph When i am pointing the head.next=head I got NPE here..

Comment: @mathlearner oh yes, I missed the curly braces. As a matter of fact, at our company we don't allow blocks like if-statements etc. without curly braces, even if there's just one statement. So add the braces for that block and it should work, provided `nNode` is not null. Again, debugging and double checking the code will help you with such cases.

Comment: is again going in the infinite loop the output is 1 2 31 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 and soo on. The same problem i am having in the starting... i am playing with this algorithm with 4 to 5 days !!

Comment: @mathlearner you're not having any ouput in your post, so either you left that out or are using a different method. Did you try and debug your code? Did you change the next reference of the _last_ node whenever you insert a node at the front, i.e. make it the new head like I said above (note that the code I gave did _not_ do this, since I was trying to show you where the problem in your code is - so that you can fix this yourself)?

Comment: i am using the same method and i got this output 

 1 2 31 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67

i have debug my code several times but i got the same output

Comment: @mathlearner you should step through your code and check when it goes into the loop and which variables are causing this. I assume (because you didn't state it) that you're adding 67 first, then 1, 2 and 31 in any order and then you add an element greater than 67. Thus 67's `next` will be initialized to itself and when you add the other nodes `67.next` will still point to `67` and thus the loop won't stop. That's what I tried to tell you with my analysis of your code and what I meant you to fix in my answer's last paragraph.

Comment: i add the element 67 31 1 2 in this pattern

Answer (score 0):

After working two days on the code I finally solved it but this is not efficient code .

```
 void insert(int e) {
        Node nNode = new Node();  //the new node, step 1: A, step2: Z
        Node tNode = head; //step1: points to B, step2: points to A
        nNode.element = e; 


        if (head == null) { //false in both steps
            head = nNode;
            head.next = head;
        }
        else if (head.element > e) {  //true in step 1, false in step 2
              Node pNode = head; 
            pNode=tNode.next;    //PNode is at head which will equal to tNode.next Which                  will be the next element
              nNode.next = head;
            head=nNode;
            tNode.next.next=nNode;   // Now I am moving the Tail Node next
        } else {

            Node pNode=head; //points to A because of step 1


            while (tNode.next != head && tNode.element <= e) {
                pNode = tNode;
                tNode = tNode.next;
            }


            pNode.next = nNode;                        
            nNode.next = tNode;

        }   
    }
```

Comment: Well, you could either iterate over the nodes until you get the last one or just store a reference in your list, just like `head`. Then you'd have to update the reference whenever you add a new tail but that shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: Your added code is also wrong, since `tNode` is initialized to the head and thus `tNode.next.next = nNode;` will set the `next` reference of the second node to the new node - whould should be the new head. This works for adding 67, 31, 1, 2 but would fail if you add 2 before 1, i.e. 67, 31, 2, 1.

Comment: yes @Thomas but some how its working correctly can you make a better code than this..?

Comment: Well, I already described what you could do: store a reference to the last node and update it when needed. I'm generally quite hesitant to provide code since it's your excercise, so you should be the one writing the code. Just make sure you test different usage patterns (more elements, duplicate elements, different order etc.) and carefully debug your code when it doesn't work as expected.